# Importing data with SQL * LOADER into two tables

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-loader

I am trying to import data into two tables but the second table cannot be imported. I followed the instruction from online but i dont where the mistake is,

my CTL file is,

```
-- THIS IS TO LOAD DATA INTO EMPTY TABLE
LOAD DATA
INFILE "C:\Component Folder\POWERHOUSEASSYLIST.csv" 
BADFILE "POWERHOUSEASSYLIST.bad" 
DISCARDFILE "POWERHOUSEASSYLIST.dsc"

INSERT INTO TABLE "MASTER_DRAWING"
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ";" OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' TRAILING NULLCOLS
( 
HEAD_MARK,
QTY,
COMP_TYPE,
PROFILE,
SURFACE,
WEIGHT,
REV_DATE "SYSDATE",
REV_NO "1"
)

INTO TABLE "FABRICATION"
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ";" OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' TRAILING NULLCOLS
( 
HEAD_MARK,
MARKING "0",
CUTTING "0",
ASSEMBLY "0",
WELDING "0",
DRILLING "0",
FINISHING "0",
REV_DATE "SYSDATE",
ID "1"
)
```

Comment: so here we go, `SMS-PW-BM1;1;BEAM;H200*100*5.5*8;4.5;125.8
SMS-PW-BM2;1;BEAM;H200*100*5.5*8;4.4;122.6
SMS-PW-BM3;1;BEAM;H300*150*6.5*9;7.0;227.9
SMS-PW-BM4;1;BEAM;H300*150*6.5*9;7.0;227.9
SMS-PW-BM5;1;BEAM;H300*150*6.5*9;6.7;214.6
SMS-PW-BM6;1;BEAM;H350*175*7*11;10.9;401.7
SMS-PW-BM7;1;BEAM;H350*175*7*11;7.9;287.9
SMS-PW-BM8;1;BEAM;H350*175*7*11;10.9;401.7`

Answer (score 1):

As per the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/ldr_control_file.htm#i1005798),

> A key point when using multiple INTO TABLE clauses is that field scanning continues from where it left off when a new INTO TABLE clause is processed.

You haven't shown your sample data. But I assume it might look something like this.

```
a;b;c;d;e;f;g;h;
1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;
```

There are only 8 columns in the data file and table MASTER_DRAWING also has 8 columns. Once it scans till the last column and loads data to 
MASTER_DRAWING, instead of going to the beginning of the line, it continues from where it stopped. But there is no data after the 8th column and hence nothing is loaded
to FABRICATION table.

You can verify this by changing few records in data file to have more than 8 columns. In that case the ninth column will be inserted INTO
FABRICATION table.

As another approach, you can use sqlloader to load MASTER_DRAWING only, and then use simple insert...select statement to fetch HEAD_MARK
from MASTER_DRAWING to FABRICATION table.

```
insert into FABRICATION
select HEAD_MARK, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, sysdate, 1
from MASTER_DRAWING;
```

Comment: here is the sample data, `SMS-PW-BM1;1;BEAM;H200*100*5.5*8;4.5;125.8
SMS-PW-BM2;1;BEAM;H200*100*5.5*8;4.4;122.6
SMS-PW-BM3;1;BEAM;H300*150*6.5*9;7.0;227.9
SMS-PW-BM4;1;BEAM;H300*150*6.5*9;7.0;227.9
SMS-PW-BM5;1;BEAM;H300*150*6.5*9;6.7;214.6
SMS-PW-BM6;1;BEAM;H350*175*7*11;10.9;401.7
SMS-PW-BM7;1;BEAM;H350*175*7*11;7.9;287.9
SMS-PW-BM8;1;BEAM;H350*175*7*11;10.9;401.7`

Comment: As i said in my answer, there are only 6 columns per record in the data file. So, nothing is loaded to second table.